# Dice game doesn't show winnings correctly

Tags: c#

I'm coding a simple dice game. The form consists of 3 textboxes and a number of labels (I'll be changing 1 textbox to a label later).
In the upper left corner the 3 dice values will appear.
Left from the gamble textbox the total amount will appear.

- in the Gamble textbox you enter your guess
- in the inzet textbox you enter the amount of money you want to wager
- in the Winnings textbox the amount of money you win should be displayed

Criteria,

- when you throw 3 sixes you get a bonus of 20
- when you throw a set of anything below 6 you get a bonus of 10
- when you throw double anything you get a bonus of 5
- when your gamble is correct your inzet is doubled (inzet = 1 you win 2)
- winnings has to display the bonus + inzet

The problem is Winnings only updates when your gamble equals total amount and seems to apply only the +5 bonus.

Here's the code:

```
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Random throwDice = new Random();
    private int total;
    private int inzet;
    private int gamble;
    private int prize;
    private int bonus;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int die1, die2, die3;

        die1 = throwDice.Next(1, 7);
        die2 = throwDice.Next(1, 7);
        die3 = throwDice.Next(1, 7);

        label1.Text = die1.ToString();
        label2.Text = die2.ToString();
        label3.Text = die3.ToString();
        label4.Text = Convert.ToString(die1 + die2 + die3);

        total = Convert.ToInt32(label4.Text);
        inzet = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        gamble = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

        if (gamble == total)
        {
            if (die1 == 6 && die1 == die2 && die1 == die3)
            {
                bonus = 20;
            }
            else if (die1 == die2 && die1 == die3)
            {
                bonus = 10;
            }
            else if (die1 == die2)
            {
                bonus = 5;
            }
            else if (die2 == die3)
            {
                bonus = 5;
            }
            else if (die1 == die3)
            {
                bonus = 5;
            }
            prize = inzet * 2 + bonus;
            textBox3.Text = prize.ToString();

        }
        else if (gamble < total && gamble > total)
        {
            if (die1 == 6 && die1 == die2 && die1 == die3)
            {
                bonus = 20;
            }
            else if (die1 == die2 && die1 == die3 )
            {
                bonus = 10;
            }
            else if (die1 == die2)
            {
                bonus = 5;
            }
            else if (die2 == die3)
            {
                bonus = 5;
            }
            else if (die1 == die3)
            {
                bonus = 5;
            }
            prize = (inzet - inzet) + bonus;
            textBox3.Text = prize.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

I need to get the 6 6 6 bonus to work (and the other set bonuses).
Also I need the bonus to apply when your gamble doesn't equal the dice total.

Comment: `prize = (inzet - inzet) + bonus;` - that's equivalent to `prize = bonus;` - was that what you intended?

Comment: `label4.Text = Convert.ToString(die1 + die2 + die3);  total = Convert.ToInt32(label4.Text);` is not the most efficient use of the variables.  Your probably would want to do `total = die1 + die2 + die3; label4.Text = total.ToString();`

Answer (score 6):

This condition:

```
    else if (gamble < total && gamble > total)
```

will never be fulfilled!

Comment: Haha how did I miss that one, if that post below this one wasnt there id probably made that into a separate else if.

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
else if (gamble < total && gamble > total)
```

This is always false. gamble can't be both less than AND greater than total.

I think what you need here is just `else`

Comment: just else did its magic, thank you, my only problem now is. Now only the bonus works. And the  gamble doesnt... and textbox3.text wont be 0 it just remembers the last bonus.

Answer (score 3):

The others answers will get to your root cause (having both < and > in the same comparison).

```
else if (gamble < total && gamble > total)
```

needs to be just:

```
else
```

This bug is a great advert for [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). Just by extracting out the results into a class (DiceResults), it's easy to test all the possible outcomes outside of the context of a running application. Right now you have duplicated logic to calculate the bonus, which in itself could easily lead to bugs if you forget to update both when changing your bonus logic.

I'm not suggesting my solution is the greatest code (as more bonus rules are added, the `if` / `else if` list will grow unwieldy - [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) can help solve that), but as a quick refactoring of your code it makes it a lot simpler to follow and ultimately, test.

I've added a few tests as an example; it would then be easy to add additional ones in order to test all outcomes. As you add to the code and make changes, you can just re-run the tests to check you haven't broken anything. If you're using Visual Studio then you can [run the unit tests easily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx).

Here's your new event handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int die1 = throwDice.Next(1, 7);
    int die2 = throwDice.Next(1, 7);
    int die3 = throwDice.Next(1, 7);

    var results = new DiceResults(die1, die2, die3);

    label1.Text = results.Dice1;
    label2.Text = results.Dice2;
    label3.Text = results.Dice3;
    label4.Text = results.GetDiceTotal();

    inzet = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    gamble = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

    int prize = results.GetPrize(gamble, inzet);
    textBox3.Text = prize;
}
```

---

And the new code to support it:

```
public class DiceResults
{
    public DiceResults(int dice1, int dice2, int dice3)
    {
        Dice1 = dice1;
        Dice2 = dice2;
        Dice3 = dice3;
    }

    public int Dice1 { get; private set; }
    public int Dice2 { get; private set; }
    public int Dice3 { get; private set; }

    public int GetBonus()
    {
        int bonus = 0;

        if (AllSixes())
        {
            bonus = 20;
        }
        else if (SetLessThanSix())
        {
            bonus = 10;
        }
        else if (AnyDouble())
        {
            bonus = 5;
        }
        return bonus;
    }

    public bool AllSixes()
    {
        return Dice1 == 6 &&
               Dice1 == Dice2 &&
               Dice2 == Dice3;
    }

    public bool SetLessThanSix()
    {
        return Dice1 < 6 &&
               Dice1 == Dice2 &&
               Dice2 == Dice3;
    }

    public bool AnyDouble()
    {
        return Dice1 == Dice2 ||
               Dice2 == Dice3 ||
               Dice1 == Dice3;
    }

    public int GetDiceTotal()
    {
        return Dice1 + Dice2 + Dice3;
    }

    public int GetPrize(int gamble, int inzet)
    {
        int prize = GetBonus();
        if (gamble == GetDiceTotal())
        {
            prize += inzet * 2;
        }
        return prize;
    }
}
```

---

And the unit tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class DiceResultsTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDiceTotal()
    {
        //Arrange
        var results = new DiceResults(1, 2, 3);

        //Act
        int diceTotal = results.GetDiceTotal();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(6, diceTotal);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestForAllSixes()
    {
        //Arrange
        var results = new DiceResults(6, 6, 6);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(results.AllSixes());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestForAllFives()
    {
        //Arrange
        var results = new DiceResults(5, 5, 5);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(results.SetLessThanSix());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestForDoubleTwo()
    {
        //Arrange
        var results = new DiceResults(2, 5, 2);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(results.AnyDouble());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestBonusForAllSixes()
    {
        //Arrange
        var results = new DiceResults(6, 6, 6);

        //Act
        int bonus = results.GetBonus();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(20, bonus);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestBonusForAllFives()
    {
        //Arrange
        var results = new DiceResults(5, 5, 5);

        //Act
        int bonus = results.GetBonus();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(10, bonus);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestBonusForDoubleTwo()
    {
        //Arrange
        var results = new DiceResults(2, 5, 2);

        //Act
        int bonus = results.GetBonus();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(5, bonus);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestBonusWhenNoBonus()
    {
        //Arrange
        var results = new DiceResults(1, 2, 3);

        //Act
        int bonus = results.GetBonus();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(0, bonus);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestPrizeForAllSixesAndCorrectGamble()
    {
        //Arrange
        var results = new DiceResults(6, 6, 6);

        //Act
        var prize = results.GetPrize(18, 50);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(120, prize);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestPrizeForAllSixesAndIncorrectGamble()
    {
        //Arrange
        var results = new DiceResults(6, 6, 6);

        //Act
        var prize = results.GetPrize(15, 50);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(20, prize);
    }

    //add more tests to cover all cases.....
}
```